# Renderizar html para múltiplas pastas no servidor

Tags: web-service, aplicação-web

Estou em busca de uma implementação que me possibilite publicar o mesmo html em vários domínios da minha hospedagem. Meu objetivo é centralizar o controle da mesma em apenas uma aplicação. Gostaria de saber se isso é possível e qual a tecnologia capaz de resolver esse problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De forma simples e pouco técnica, mas que te dê margem para avançar:

1. Apontar o DNS de todos os domínios para o mesmo servidor;
2. Configurar o servidor web (nginx/apache/iis) para direcionar TUDO para o mesmo diretório;

Isso fará com que seu sistema esteja acessível independente se o usuário veio de `www.dominio1.com.br` ou `www.dominio48.com.lo`.

Daí caberá a sua aplicação identificar isso internamente e fazer o que você quiser.

Se atente ao controlador de Sessão da aplicação, isso pode estar atrelado ao dominio e precise tratar.

Se você implementar mais informações a sua pergunta, posso implementar mais detalhes aqui para facilitar.